# Iframe somehow not working (shows as a blank page)

Tags: html, css

i just get into a small problem.
i tried to include iframe inside and also outside of `div` code but nothing show
adding like `frameborder="0"`,etc didn't work either
then i tried on another .html file to make sure the iframe is good and it's showing like usually.
so why the iframe won't opened the src file, did i do something wrong ?.
heres my code (the problematic one):

```
       <html>
            <head>
                    <title>Buat.in</title>
            </head>
                    <body class="container">
            <div>
                    <div class="additional-ui">
                    </div>
                            <div>
                                    <iframe src="backgroundui.html">    
                                    </iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-bttnmenu">
                                    <ul>
                                            <li>Tentang
                                            </li>
                                            <li>Daftar Desain
                                            </li>
                                            <li>Lokasi
                                            </li>
                                            <li>Hubungi
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                    <footer class="foot-ui">
                    <p>Designed & Written by :</p>
```

and also i haven't applying the separate style file here, the `class=""` will be linked to my style later, i test it on firefox 85.0.1 ubuntu.

(Edit) heres the additional info for backgroundui.html:

```
<html>
    <body class="secondary-ui-container">
            <h1>Buat.in</h1>
            <p>Your "trusted designer"</p>
            </body>
</html>
```

fun fact theres something happened, when i run `iframe` inside the background.html (supposed to be the ui) the iframe works normally else on the main page.
or should i rebuild all from zero again ?.

Comment: Add `width` and `height` attributes

Comment: still not showing anything.

Comment: paste the content for backgroundui.html.

Comment: i edited + added the backgroundui.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox has recently implemented a security feature which does not allow cross tab tracking which is the fundamental of iFrame. Previously, this feature only prevented only https and ssl certified sites.

You may change this behavior in your own Firefox installation by typing about:config in the address bar and setting **security.mixed_content.block_active_content** to **false**.

Here are some  more docs about x-frame-options:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: i guess i'll try this method first, i sure the code isn't the problem. (edit)okay, it's seems the firefox won't opened the iframe because the security issue, now it's display the backgroundui.html normally, thanks :).